# How to compare two dates found by fstat()

Tags: c, time

I am trying to see which file has been modified most recently. How do I compare the dates found to find the most recent?

```
localtime_r(&file_info.st_mtime), &time);
asctime_r(&time, asctime_str);


localtime_r(&file_info2.st_mtime), &time2);
asctime_r(&time2, asctime_str2);
```

Comment: If you use `stat()` to get the file statistics/ properties the struct field `st_atime` gives the most recent access time in seconds since 1/1/1970.

Comment: BTW: post real code.

Answer (score 2):

`time_t` which is the type of the `st_mtime` member in the `struct stat` structure is an integer-type.  You can directly compare them with the `<` operator.  The smaller one will be the older timestamp.